# Disabling the submit button until the form data matches all the validations?

Tags: jquery, forms

As working on form validation using JQuery i have applied all validations on the text fields but unable to fix the submit button condition.

Submit button condition: By default submit button is 'disabled'. When all text fields matches all the validations it should be enabled which is not happening.
All my 7 text fields are set to 'false' when they don't match the validation then they will become 'true'.

```
$("#reg_form").submit(function(){

            error_firstName = false;
            error_lastName = false;
            error_emailAdd = false;
            error_pass = false;
            error_confirmPass = false;
            error_mobile = false;
            error_confirmMob = false;

            check_FirstName();
            check_LastName();
            check_email();
            check_password();
            check_confirm_password();
            check_Mobile();
            check_cMobile();

            validate();

            $("#form_firstName,#form_lasttName,#form_email,#form_pass,#form_cPass,#form_mob,#form_cMob").change(validate);

            function validate(){

                if(error_firstName === false && error_lastName === false && error_emailAdd === false && error_pass === false && error_confirmPass === false && error_mobile === false && error_confirmMob === false){
                    $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled",false);
                    return true;
                }
                else{
                    $("input[type=submit]").prop('disabled',true);
                    return false;
                }   
            }

    });
```

So please correct me with this and save a life,thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this `#form_lasttName` supposed to contain two `t`?

Comment: Your events are on submit you don't have any events before submiting the form ???

Comment: try or condition (error_firstName === false || error_lastName === false) like this

Comment: Output all error flags like this `console.log("error_firstName=" + error_firstName);` and see which one is not false.

Answer (score 0):

it easy and better to use jquery-validation then custom validation.
example:

Html

```
<form id="form-signin_v1" name="form-signin_v1" method="POST">
    <label>
        Username
        <input name="signin_v1[username]" type="text" data-validation="[NOTEMPTY]">
    </label>
    <label>
        Password
        <input name="signin_v1[password]" type="password" data-validation="[NOTEMPTY]">
    </label>
    <input type="submit" class="ui blue submit button" value="Login">
</form>
```

javascript

```
$('#form-signin_v1').validate();
```

official website : https://jqueryvalidation.org/ try it.

Answer (score 0):

This would probably be the easiest way without having to use any extra libraries. I've not tested the code but shouldn't be hard to tweak.

```
$('#reg_form').on('change', 'input', function(){

    // Do your validation on this item
    // On validation add .valid or .invalid classes to the inputs


    // Find all inputs that aren't valid (class .valid) and aren't submit buttons
    var incorrect = $('#reg_form').find('input:not(.valid):not(type="submit")').length;

    // Add/Disable disabled property based on number of incorrect inputs
    $("input[type=submit]").prop("disabled", incorrect > 0);

});
```